# How do I create a Userform that returns names in a listbox and two checkbox options?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a userform that returns the name from a Listbox and corresponding "days" and "Amounts" for that name selected from the Listbox (name, amount and days are all ranges on a spreadsheet).

My userform and the spreadsheet are attached below.

My code so far:

```vb
Private Sub BtnCancel_Click()
MsgBox ("Report Cancelled")
Unload FrmCust
End Sub


Private Sub BtnOk_Click()

' msgbox showing the user's selection, as well 
' as days and amount if selected in the checkboxes

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' Fill the listbox with each user's name

  Dim cell As Range

'Load to ListBox

  FrmCust.ListBoxCustlist.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle 'allows only one selection

  For Each cell In Worksheets("Data").Range("J3:j17")
    ListBoxCustlist.AddItem cell.Value
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Userform and related spreadsheet

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you are currently using for this in your question if you would like help with it.

Comment: Userforms dont really "return" something, but you can use `Me.Hide` on the OK_Click event to hide the form, and then process the user's selections there as well.

Comment: sounds good, i've added.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in your code show that you would just like some MsgBox code to show the selected values. (You did not include the names of your checkbox controls, so I used Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 respectively. Modify those to match the names of your checkbox controls.)

```
If ListBoxCustlist.ListIndex = -1 Then
  MsgBox "No Item was selected"
Else
  MsgBox ListBoxCustlist.List(ListBoxCustlist.ListIndex, 0) & " - Days=" & CheckBox1.Value & " - Amount=" & CheckBox2.Value
  ' Me.Hide ' Optionally hide the form
End If
```

**Update** : *I'd like it to take the average of each person in the list with that name*

Well that's much more complex, but this should work:

```
Private Sub BtnOk_Click()
  If ListBoxCustlist.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No Item was selected"
  Else
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim dDayCount As Object
    Dim dDayValue As Object
    Dim dAmountCount As Object
    Dim dAmountValue As Object
    Set dDayCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dDayValue = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dAmountCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dAmountValue = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim sPerson As String

    lLastRow = 17

    sPerson = ListBoxCustlist.List(ListBoxCustlist.ListIndex, 0)
    With Worksheets("Data")
      For lRow = 3 To lLastRow
        If .Range("A" & lRow).Value = sPerson Then
          If Not dDayCount.Exists(sPerson) Then
            dDayCount.Add sPerson, 1
            dAmountCount.Add sPerson, 1
            dDayValue.Add sPerson, .Range("B" & lRow).Value
            dAmountValue.Add sPerson, .Range("C" & lRow).Value
          Else
            dDayCount.Item(sPerson) = dDayCount.Item(sPerson) + 1
            dDayValue.Item(sPerson) = dDayValue.Item(sPerson) + .Range("B" & lRow).Value
            dAmountCount.Item(sPerson) = dAmountCount.Item(sPerson) + 1
            dAmountValue.Item(sPerson) = dAmountValue.Item(sPerson) + .Range("C" & lRow).Value
          End If
        End If
      Next
    End With

    Dim sResult As String
    sResult = sPerson & ": "
    If CheckBox1 Then
      If dDayCount.Item(sPerson) = 0 Then
        sResult = sResult & "Days AVG=0"
      Else
        sResult = sResult & "Days AVG=" & dDayValue.Item(sPerson) / dDayCount.Item(sPerson)
      End If
      If CheckBox2 Then sResult = sResult & " : "
    End If
    If CheckBox2 Then
      If dAmountCount.Item(sPerson) = 0 Then
        sResult = sResult & "Amount AVG=0"
      Else
        sResult = sResult & "Amount AVG=" & dAmountValue.Item(sPerson) / dAmountCount.Item(sPerson)
      End If
    End If

    MsgBox sResult

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies, I should clarify. By values, I meant the cell values in columns B & C if they're selected that correspond to the name in the listbox

Comment: Meaning the `Sum` of those values for the selected person? Or each individual value? You have multiple values for each person in some cases.

Comment: I'd like it to take the average of each person in the list with that name

Comment: thank you so much for the help. but do you mind clarifying what scripting dictionary is? I'm pretty new to VBA so I've never seen that before. thanks again

Comment: It lets you build lists using key items for quick lookups later - here's the docs - https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/excel-vba-dictionary-keys-and-items/

Comment: If you wanted to, you could even use one to build the unique list for your listbox instead of using your person list in column J. Combined with making the number of rows dynamic, that would make for a much more robust solution, but that was not part of your question, so i left that alone.

Comment: Also, im getting an overflow error when i try to run that, do you have a suggestion how to change it?

Comment: are you trying to divide by zero? does some of your data not have any values?

Comment: from what i can tell, nothing is being divided by 0. I changed it a little bit so each If condition has its own messagebox, and i'm getting the overflow error in the average days if statement.

Comment: average days if statement? can you show me what line by pasting it here? is it a line that you changed?

Comment: updated the answer to show where im getting the overflow error. It is coming from the line : sResult = MsgBox(" Their average days in receivables is " & (dDayValue.Item(sPerson) / dDayCount.Item(sPerson)) & " days.")

Comment: I saw it and put it back, because you are not using the updated code. I added a check for `If dDayCount.Item(sPerson) = 0 Then` that you are not uncluding.